# How to launch one activity by clicking on the button

Tags: android

I want to call next activity from the first activity.
When user click on the button then it will call the next activity .
please suggest me how can i do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
```

You would need to do this either in the OnClickListener for your button, or in a method you've declared to be called when you click on the button in your xml